# Viewing React app running on a WSL2 machine

Tags: create-react-app, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am developing a create-react-app on Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL2. I am trying to view the app from my iPhone that is connected to the same network. I can access the app if I clone the repo and run it from Windows 10 but I can't seem to connect to WSL. I have tried the IP address that the webserver says to use:

```
Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://1xx.xx.xx.x:3000
```

but that doesn't work. Has anyone experienced this problem before?